# How add access to cookie in Django views

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-rest-framework, jwt

Hello friends i am beginner and i have a code that i added it below .

i have view that uses as refresh_token .
my boss tell to me adde access to cookie but i do not know how to add it ?where to add it?
can anyone give me a solution or send me a link about it?
if have less knowledge about cookie and and complete request structure if can me a link for describe that i am thankful.

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from src.apps.accounts.services import refresh
from src.errors import BadRequestException, ErrorEnum
from settings import ACCESS_TTL
from django.core.cache import cache
```

class RefreshToken(APIView):
permission_classes = []

```
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    refresh_token = self.request.data.get("refresh_token")
    if refresh_token is None:
        raise BadRequestException(
            message={
                "refresh_token": _("refresh_token must be submitted.")
            },
            error_type=[ErrorEnum.RefreshToken.REFRESH_IS_EMPTY],
        )
    access_token, refresh_token = refresh(token=refresh_token)

    response= Response(
        data={
            "ok": True,
            "data": {
                "access_token": access_token,
                "refresh_token": refresh_token,
            },
            "status": status.HTTP_200_OK,
        },
        status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
        headers={"HTTP_ACCESS":access_token},
    )
    return response
```

Comment: Please remove the image and add the code so that people here can better answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the token in cookies like this:

```
def your_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse()
    response.set_cookie('access_token', your_access_token, httpOnly=True)
    response.set_cookie('refresh_token', your_refresh_token, httpOnly=True)
    return response
```

and you can get it with `request.COOKIES['access_token']`

You can also return cookie in header like this:

```
headers = {
  'Set-Cookie': 'access_token='+ access_token+';'
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but we use "from rest_framework.response import Response" and in Response i cant find set_cookie method . i add it in header like this ---->headers={"HTTP_ACCESS":access_token} but i do not know is it true?

Comment: Edit answers check again

Comment: @fahime if this fixed your issue please mark as accepted and if you think it will help future readers you can upvote :)

Comment: yes it resolve but i cant find where i must add it as accepted

Comment: @fahime Just click the tick mark and to upvote just hit up arrow.